# Is it better to delete questions I've asked than to ask for them to be closed?

Tags: support

I've asked a couple of questions, [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/191696/25656) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/177695/25656) that haven't been answered after quite a while. I see no way to improve them. I have asked that they be closed. But, on reflection, would it be better to have them deleted? How does closing a question rather than deleting it affect AskUbuntu's stats?

Comment: I've tacked some bounties on them, let's see if that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just leave those two open, they seem to be fine questions, just not getting attention.

Though you haven't really added anything to them since you asked them; you should at least try to add some results of your research into them if possible; surely there's *something* out there that you've found that might be related that you can add to the questions.

Comment: For the browser question, I did post a related question at the [Launchpad Q&A](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+question/209284) and in [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12252422) but didn't get any feedback to enhance the Ask Ubuntu question here. For the theme question, I did ask at [Launchpad Q&A](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+question/206347) as well but didn't get much to pass back here. It's true I could have pushed things further but I guess I lacked the motivation.